# Bluebird Promise: Is is possible to have multiple reject() in new Promise(function (resolve, reject)?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Example:

```
function multiRejectExample(){ 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    if(statement){
      console.log('statement 1');
      reject(throw new Error('error'));
    }
   if(statement){
     console.log('statement 2');
     reject(throw new Error('error')); 
   }
  });
}
```

I'm using bluebird. Is the above okay to do? Is it bad practice?

Also, if it rejects in the first statement, why does 'statement 2' still print out? I want to return if 'rejected', how to I do this?

Is it better to use Promise.try and then throw the error? Help! Thank you!

Comment: The `reject()` call is just a function call. It doesn't cause the calling function to return.

Comment: What should I do to get desired outcome?

Comment: Maybe add a `return` after the `reject()` call, if that's what you want it to do. Or use `else if` in subsequent tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is is possible to have multiple reject() in new Promise(function
>   (resolve, reject)?

Yes, you can have multiple places that you might call `reject()` for a promise.  This is generically true for Promises and is not just a Bluebird feature.

A promise is a one-way state machine.  Once it has been rejected with a reason, it will NOT change its state again.

> I'm using bluebird. Is the above okay to do? Is it bad practice?

It isn't an error to call `reject()` more than once on the same promise, but only the first call to `reject()` will be recorded and be the reason for the rejection in the promise.  Subsequent calls to `reject()` for the same promise will be ignored.

If you know your function is done doing what it needed to do and has called `reject()` and no other code needs to execute in that function, then it is bad practice to just let the rest of your code continue to execute.  Depending upon what that code is, it might not do any harm, but it would be a better practice to just `return` when you're done.

> Also, if it rejects in the first statement, why does 'statement 2'
>   still print out? I want to return if 'rejected', how to I do this?

Calling `reject()` does not stop your function from executing.  It just changes the state of the promise.  Your function still continues to execute and then after your function is done, the `.then()` handler for the promise will be triggered.  If you want to execute no more code in your function after you call `reject()`, you can just use a `return` statement.

---

In your particular case, it would probably make more sense to just `return` after you reject if no other code needs to be run after that, but it is not necessary:

```
function multiRejectExample(){ 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    if(statement){
      console.log('statement 1');
      reject(new Error('error'));
      return;
    }
   if(statement){
     console.log('statement 2');
     reject(new Error('error')); 
     return;
   }
  });
}
```

See example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gtq49v9x/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Don't call `throw` when calling `reject()`, just `return reject(new Error('error'));`

Comment: @Erhhung - Corrected, not sure why the `throw` was in there, though it probably worked the way it was because the throw is caught as a rejection too, but it should have only had one or the other.